# Python script for `docker run` command for Watchtower

Tags: python, docker, containers

I want to run the following Docker container via a Python script.

```
docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock containrrr/watchtower --run-once
```

So far I've gotten this using the [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.ContainerCollection.run) documents.

```
bindVolume = {'/var/run/docker.sock': {'bind': '/var/run/docker.sock', 'mode': 'rw'}}

client.containers.run('containrrr/watchtower', name="watchtower", volumes = bindVolume, auto_remove=True
```

But how do I call `--run-once`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
client.containers.run('containrrr/watchtower',command=["--run-once"], name="watchtower", volumes = bindVolume, auto_remove=True)
```

> command (str or list) – The command to run in the container.

see [this](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/examples/)